# Basic File/Post restriction plugin

Tags: uploads, security, permissions, content-restriction

I am looking for a plugin that allows me to restrict access for a individual post/page to a specific role or individual.  It also needs to restrict files attached to that post.  I have tried several but none seem to have this complete combination or just dont work.  What is the best plugin to achieve this or will I have to roll my own?

I have tried:

- Role Scoper
- Members
- User Access Manager

Comment: Well, would be nice if you listed in your Question the plugins you have already tried...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)? One of the best I've worked with so far.

Comment: `It also needs to restrict files attached to that post` — the plugin does that? (considering "files" could very well be images)

Comment: "restrict files" is exceptionally vague, so I suggested a plugin that might get @kidbrax off the ground. It's got a very intuitive roles/capability manager, which they could use to grant/remove custom caps, & then plug into the default upload process.

Comment: `"restrict files" is exceptionally vague` — was thinking the same — I don't see a way other than HTTP pass authentication or IP blocking.

Comment: yes, Role Scoper supposedly does this but just doesn't work.  They supposedly do it by altering htaccess to restrict all downloads and then when someone clicks on a link, they use php to grab the file and deliver it.  But as I said, it just doesn't work.  He has a new paid version of the plugin but the file restriction piece is not included as of yet.